# Insertar un valor en el arreglo

Tags: c#

¿Cómo podría agregar y borrar un valor a este arreglo (vector)?

```
int[] arregloConValores = { 3, 106, 77, 0, 0, 0 };

//Elementos máximo del arreglo
int elementos = 6;

//Datos guardados en el arreglo
int cantidad = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es que no se puede eliminar o agregar elementos a un vector, si somos rigurosos con las definiciones y la terminología, ya que un vector no cambia de tamaño para agregar o eliminar elementos. Es decir, un vector es siempre de tamaño fijo, como indica la propiedad [IsFixedSize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.isfixedsize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_IsFixedSize).

Sin embargo, puedes sustituir un elemento por otro, y como se ve en tu ejemplo, tener una variable que indique cuántos elementos significativos se ha "introducido" en el vector.

Si declaras un vector de un tamaño grande, y lo tomas como huecos que puedes rellenar con elementos, puedes en cierta manera considerar que "agregas" y "eliminas" elementos.

```
// Inicialización
int[] vector = new int[100];
int numeroElementos = 0;

// "Agregar" un elemento
vector[numeroElementos] = 5;
numeroElementos++;

// "Elimino" un elemento
numeroElementos--;
```

La clave está en que la variable `numeroElementos` apunta al primer "hueco" libre del vector, y al mismo tiempo nos dice cuántos elementos hemos introducido en el mismo (en realidad estamos tratando al vector como si fuera una lista).

Ahora bien, si introducimos elementos, llegará un momento en que lleguemos a llenarlo por completo, y ya no podremos agregar más elementos, porque como he dicho, no podemos re dimensionar un vector.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es crear un vector más grande, y copiar los elementos del antiguo vector al nuevo, y guardar la referencia al nuevo vector en la antigua variable. Es casi como re dimensionar el vector, pero teniendo que copiarlo, con lo que hay un gasto en tiempo y memoria añadido.

```
// Creamos un vector con un tamaño inicial por defecto
int vectorSize = 100;
int[] vector = new int[vectorSize];
int numeroElementos = 0;

// Si en algún momento detectamos que se llena
if (numeroElementos == vectorSize)
{
    int nuevoSize = vectorSize * 2;
    int[] copia = new int[nuevoSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++) copia[i] = vector[i];
    vector = copia;
    vectorSize = nuevoSize;
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", arregloConValores[i]);
            Console.WriteLine();

            //Insertar
            Console.WriteLine("Añadiendo 6 al final");
            if (cantidad < elementos)
            {
                arregloConValores[cantidad] = 6;
                cantidad++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
                Console.Write("{0} ", arregloConValores[i]);
            Console.WriteLine();

Comment: ya lo ise al lo arregle con eso

Comment: @IsRael_tORRES si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, considera marcarla como aceptada